# WebSocket error in Unity WebGL multiplayer game using Photon

Tags: multiplayer, unity-webgl, photon-pun

Using Photon Realtime in Unity WebGL multiplayer game, when I play game 2nd or 3rd time giving this error and photon is getting disconnected after this error, I am running games on Firefox browser, using UDP protocol and the error is also occurring in photon’s demo games, there is no specific url on which this error is occurring i just did build and run. The last time i tested this is 11:40 am(IST). Here is a console log -

The main 3 errors after which client is getting dissconneted are -

1. WebSocket connection to 'wss://f07fe4ef715d0928f673e26d4ad414c4.exitgames.com/game/?libversion=4.1.6.17&sid=30&app=f10ae04b-765c-4345-a09b-a14e7a56f8ff&IPv6' failed
2. writeStringToMemory is deprecated and should not be called! Use stringToUTF8() instead!
3. Exiting receive thread. Server: wss://F07FE4EF715D0928F673E26D4AD414C4.exitgames.com:443/game Error: Abnormal disconnection.

I tried starting the connection again but still getting this error.